# How do I find good approximations to a search in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, lucene, mongodb-query

I don't know how this type of search is called.

If I have this document in a collection:

```
{city : 'brazil'}
```

is there a way of finding it by searching

```
'brasil'
```

with the full text search feature?
Or it is only possible with Lucene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. MongoDB doesn't have all the features of a dedicated full text search library/engine like Lucene/Solr. In this case what you're looking for would be fuzzy search or spelling correction, or possibly some kind of multilingual pack.